# What is going on with deltaTime in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, frame-rate

Firstly I want to mention, that I'm making my first project ever in Unity engine so the issue might be quite silly. As far as I know Time.deltaTime and Time.fixedDeltaTime store the approximate time between frames (graphics and physics). I wanted to implement a simple fps counter to my game. Function is written below:

```
void FPS_Counter()
 {
     float frequency_physics = 1f/Time.fixedDeltaTime;
     float frequency_graphics = 1f/Time.deltaTime;
     fps.text = "Phys: " + frequency_physics.ToString("N0") + "\n" + "Graph: " + frequency_graphics.ToString("N0");
 }
```

FPS_Counter() is called in Update(). The script always outputs values of 50[hz] for both fixed and "normal" delta times. It seems that frequency is locked on 50 fps. Is this a normal behaviour? Does Unity lock calling FixedUpdate() and update() at 50hz? If so, can I change this value somewhere to see how much fps can I really get?

Comment: If you have VSync on and the update rate of the physics simulation is set to 0.02ms (the default one) then those results are to be expected

Comment: fixedDeltaTime will always be 0.02f, by default. Time.DeltaTime however, will vary, on the processing time of each frame :)

Comment: See the manual on [Time Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TimeManager.html) and [Quality Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-QualitySettings.html) for how to change those

Comment: @HåvardNygård not true, you can change the fixedDeltaTime in the Time Manager (see my previous comment)

Comment: Oh @UnholySheep i will modify my comment. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be many reasons to why the FPS is locked to a spesific rate. The Time.deltaFixedTime variable however, is always locked to a spesific update value. By Default it is: 0.02 secs, between each fixed update.

If you want a FPS counter for debugging, i can give you a refrence to this: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=FramesPerSecond

Reasons to why the framerate is locked, might be, as @UnholySheep said, Vsync, computer limits (although it would most likely bounce around) and some other reasons.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-QualitySettings.html 
Here is a link, to where you can turn off VSync, if it shall turn out to be on.

Comment: IIRC VSync Count is by default set to "Every VBlank" (but I haven't used Unity in a while, so I'm not 100% certain about that)

Comment: Checked, can confirm.